# Display one text field on click from a set number of text fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a form where users have 10 text fields. But initially only 1 text field is shown. If the user needs to enter more data they can click on the **add one** button and then displays the next text field from the maximum of 10.

like so:

[image]

Im working with angular.js so I thought about using ng-show to hide & show fields.

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pointOne" ng-show="pointOne">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pointTwo" ng-show="pointTwo">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pointThree" ng-show="pointThree">
<span><button ng-click="addOne()">Add One</button></span>
</div>
```

I am unable to figure out the most effective way to doing this. Any hints, help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: How about ng-repeat?

Comment: ng-repeat and a variable you increment each time the user adds a field. Then test the $index agaist the variable to show the fields.

Comment: @snookieordie any chance you can provide an example?

Comment: @lansen any chance you can provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go the Angular route, I'd suggest using `ng-repeat`. Here's a fiddle that might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it shows how to use ng-repeat and you can modify as needed:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvsnao97/5/

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="add_input()">Add Input</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-repeat="x in random_array" name="point{{$index}}">
</body>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.random_array = [0]  
    $scope.add_input = function() {
        var i = $scope.random_array.length
        $scope.random_array.push(i)
    }
}]);
```

When you want a new `<input>`, you simply push a new element to `$scope.random_array`.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I will test it out now and update accordingly

Comment: I ended up using your answer. It worked perfectly, I also tried to pass the `$index` to another function which uses `splice` to remove the text fields from the array but after splicing it messes up the remaining array.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it but this is how I would do it:

```
   <div class="form-group" >
    <input ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number)" type="text" class="form-control" name="point{{i}}" ng-show="$index<=counter">
    <span><button ng-click="addOne()">Add One</button></span>
</div>
```

And in your controller just add something like this:

```
$scope.number = 10;
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}

$scope.counter=0;
$scope.addOne= function() {
    $scope.counter++;  
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I will test it out now and update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily add elements to the DOM:

```
function createPetField() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = 'pet[]';
  return input;
}

var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
document.getElementById('addPet').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  form.appendChild(createPetField());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably good way is to make array of input fields and then ng-repeat them. When user clicks on AddOne, then just push input field in array, and it will be there.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <html>
        <head>
        <title>jQuery add / remove textbox</title>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            div{
                padding:8px;
            }
        </style>

        </head>

        <body>

        <h1>jQuery add / remove textbox example</h1>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var counter = 2;

            $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if(counter>10){
                    alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                    return false;
            }   

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                 .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
                  '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


            counter++;
             });

             $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if(counter==1){
                  alert("No more textbox to remove");
                  return false;
               }   

            counter--;

                $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

             });

             $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

            var msg = '';
            for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
              msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
            }
                  alert(msg);
             });
          });
        </script>
        </head><body>

        <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
            <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
        <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
        <input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

JQuery can be used to add inputs in your `addOne()` method.

Like so:

```js
var maxInputs = 10;
var currentInput = 0;

function addOne() {
  currentInput++;
  if (currentInput > maxInputs) {
    currentInput = maxInputs;
    return;
  }
  var name = "point" + currentInput;
  var $input = $("<input type='text' class='form-control' name='" + name + "' ng-show='" + name + "'>");


  $(".form-group").append($input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <span><button onclick="addOne()">Add One</button></span>
</div>
```